# Release APK Not Updating With JavaScript Code

Tags: android, react-native

My Android APK is running off the `JavaScript` present when I generated the first signed APK. I've tried cleaning/rebuilding the project in Android Studio, I've tried `./gradlew clean` in the `android` subfolder. Any ideas as to why the code isn't updating? I've seen [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6745), without any success for myself.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I deleted the `index.android.*` files in `android/app/src/main/assets/` directory. Then in the project root, ran

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Then I regenerated the signed APK and voila!

EDIT: If you are using a newer project, you may not have an `index.android.js` only `index.js`. If that's the case, you'll want to change it to:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Comment: this must be done every time we submit a new build? Is there a permanent fix?

Comment: @Avery235 yes, you have to bundle the JavaScript for the apk. If you don't bundle for iOS it just uses the packager I believe. Not sure if there's a way to do the same for Android

Comment: any idea why I get an error because I don't have an index.android.js?

Comment: As per release 0.49 (september 2017) there is no index.android.js and no index.ios.js. Only index.js (unique file for both of them)

Comment: That was my solution after 3 hours of banging my head at the keyboard... Thanks man

Comment: @MattyK14 can you please explain why do I always have to run the second line of code in your solution? I now need to run it always before compiling my App

Comment: @ShubhamBisht for development or release? It's necessary for release because you need to bundle the JavaScript. If you have to do it for development, you'll need to configure your device properly to communicate with your packager.

Comment: I found that if the old APK is still around, a new one may not get created. So I also do `rm android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-*`

Answer (score 8):

1.Delete (`index.android.bundle`) files inside directory `android/app/src/main/assets`.

2.run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

3.Delete folders (`drawable,drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi,raw`) inside `android/app/src/main/res`

4.run `react-native run-android --variant=release`

IF NOT WORKING TRY THIS `https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/127#issuecomment-502574735`

Answer (score 2):

if you were using EXPO and you have ejected the app, the build process still pass through EXPO's server. In order:
from the project root folder publish the changes to EXPO:

```
expo-cli publish
```

then, once it is finished, from within the android root folder:

```
gradle assembleDebug
```

or

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 2):

run this in react-native project termanil:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Answer (score 1):

The below commands worked for me ...

```
1. cd android

2. gradlew clean

3. gradlew assembleRelease
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When i used  assembleRelease, it generated older apk.

Adding below config to `app/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.react = [
  bundleInRelease: true
]
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

follow 2 steps only given below:

//firstly make build as Debug.

1. =>  ./gradlew assembleDebug

//then make build as Release.

2. => ./gradlew assembleRelease

it works for many. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so instead here's a long automation for Noe Fabellon's suggestion (which worked for me)

From the project root directory

```
rm android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && rm -R android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi android/app/src/main/res/raw || true && cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .. && react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Answer (score 0):

cd android
gradlew clean
goto AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\assets and delete index.android.bundle file
cd..
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
gradlew assembleRelease

worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your project is running older version of react-native. Then try these steps:

1. Go to android folder of your project
2. Run ./gradlew clean
3. Run ./gradlew app:assembleRelease
4. Now, go to your android studio and create the signed bundle apk by navigating to the build option.

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar issue, if none of the solutions are working for you this one should work:

1. cd android
2. gradlew clean
3. goto *AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\assets* and **delete** *index.android.bundle file*
4. cd..
5. react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
6. gradlew assembleRelease