# Android App showing new version on play store, but downloading old APK

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I have submitted an update to my Android app on the Google Play Console and it was approved, and shows newest version on Google Play Store.

However, when I download app on Play Store, the old version APK is what is downloaded, not the new version.

I have tried clearing Play Store cache, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling app, but still old APK. This is troubling because it shows that I am downloading the newest version.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does the new version support the same OS versions as the old one? Possibly, the newer version only supports higher versions of the OS, so older devices are being served the old version.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441217/release-apk-not-updating-with-javascript-code) answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to check. The first is look at the version code of the app you are downloading. If you are the developer of the app, using adb you can pull the app off the phone using:

`adb shell dumpsys package my.package | grep version`

The version code is the definitive thing that will tell you if the new version of the app is on your phone. If the version code is the new version, but the code seems to be doing the old thing, then you made a mistake when submitting your APK.

If the version code is the old version, then a few things could have happened:

- The Play store has to update lots of different caches in different data centers around the world, and this can take a little while. Try waiting 15 minutes and seeing if things get better.
- You could have accidentally left your old version of your app live, and the old version is compatible with your phone, but the new version isn't.
- this could really be a bug with Play. If so, use the "contact us" link on [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/#topic=3450769), and they might be able to look at your account and see the problem