# Released apk not reflecting changes made on source code

Tags: apk, react-native

No matter the changes i do, the release apk is not upated, i'have tried all the solutions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441217/release-apk-not-updating-with-javascript-code) and none off them worked. It is odd because if i run `react-native run-android` everything works fine! Am i missing something? What have I do wrong?

I'm using RN 0.60.5 on PC, is this helps.

Comment: are you sure you have run this command before generating a new apk ? 

```react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res```

Comment: Yes, I did. And now it throws me an error of duplicate files in `row` folder. I also tried this solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22234) and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning the gradle before you build a release apk

`cd android  && ./gradlew clean` after cleaning you can also stop all the running gradle `./gradlew --stop` and after the gradle is cleaned you can create an apk `./gradlew assembleRelease` or you can create an aab `./gradlew bundleRelease`

Hope this helps