# React-native latest changes/code is not being reflected in the build after running assembleRelase command

Tags: react-native

I am facing the problem with my release apk which is not updated with my latest code(If i made any changes in code, that reflects locally but not reflecting in release apk). I am using ./gradlew assembleRelease.
I have tried several solutions as
[Release APK Not Updating With JavaScript Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441217/release-apk-not-updating-with-javascript-code)

I have shared my build.gradle file for reference.

```
   buildscript {
    ext {
       buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
       minSdkVersion = 19
       compileSdkVersion = 29
       targetSdkVersion = 29
      }
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
   }

    allprojects {
     repositories {
     mavenLocal()
      maven {
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
     }
     maven {
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
     }
     maven { 
        url 'https://maven.cashfree.com/release'
     }

      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
   }
```

Comment: does anyone knows how to solve this issue.

Comment: you found any solution?

Comment: Yeah, try cleaning gradle cache. It worked for me.